# AutoLayout in nib file for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nib

I'm trying to re-create my UITableViewCell in a .xib so I can re-use it in multiple views.  No matter what I do I can't seem to get AutoLayout to do its job when loading my .xib.  I've tried setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false when I deque the cell.  Any ideas as to what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You should add some code to show what you have done so far.

Comment: Why do you need a xib to reuse the cell? Just create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and you can reuse it all your want.

Comment: @maddy - I need to re-use a UITableViewCell layout in multiple views.  I prefer not setting my view in code, but using the designer.  I definitely have the a custom subclass of UITableViewCell, but I want to pair that with my layout in .xib file

Comment: @James Scott are you setting constraint programatically?

Comment: are you adding constraints to the view after you init from Nib ? E.g myView = UINIB(...) then using autolayout on myView, if so you do need translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false in awakeFromNib on the myView

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I've finally got this figured out.  It goes against other recommendations I've read online, but this is what I did.  I basically had two problems:

1) My vertical constraints were not defined perfectly all the way down.  In my case I had a vertical stack view, with other stack views embedded inside, but my main vertical stack view did not have a bottom constraint.  Adding the bottom constraint fixed it.

2) Also:  I've ran into problems with .xib (nibs) before where setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false makes it auto -layout properly.  In my case it was calling this that was creating the problem.  Removing this setting and making sure my constraints were defined all the way down seems to have worked.